# Null pointer com Location Manager

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Tenho o seguinte código o qual retorna `NullPointerException` na linha: `lat = location.getLatitude();`

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private String provider;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    double lat =0;
    double lng =0;
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(21.000,-51.000)));
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
    if (provider != null){
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Perdemos Você",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Detalhe estou usando Android Studio!

Comment: Esse `onLocationChanged()` por acaso quer dizer que sua activity está implementando `LocationListener`? Porque se for, o objetivo não é chamá-lo explicitamente e sim esperar que o GPS obtenha uma nova posição e chame esse método sem você precisar fazê-lo (nota: isso só vai acontecer se antes disso você chamar `requestLocationUpdates()`). É assim que se obtém novas posições. O método `getLastKnownLocation()` somente retorna a última posição obtida dessa maneira que falei, antes disso ele não retorna nada mesmo.

Comment: sim implemento LocationListener! Muito Obrigado pela Dica! ñ tinha analisado essa possibilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que fazer uma verificação se o objeto esta nulo antes de tentar acessar o método do mesmo, algo assim:

```
if(location != null){
  lat = location.getLatitude();
  lng = location.getLongitude();
  onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

O jeito que voce esta implementando o `LocationManager`, o `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)`, busca a ultima localização conhecida  do GPS, não sei se e isso que voce quer, mas [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) na documentação tem as melhores formas de fazer isso.

Comment: Deu Boa! Só preciso ainda ver que diz que estou com a rede desabilitada, Grato1

Comment: A ideia é atualizar em "Tempo Real", mas tenho que mexer bastante, vou dar uma olhada na documentação para implementar de maneira melhor!